# Is is possible to recover files form a hard drive after it was "zeroed out"?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery

I have an external hard drive, on which I had many important things that I don't have another copy of. Something was messed up with the partitioning of the hard drive, since it showed up as a 600 and something GB partition, where as the hard drive itself is a 1 TB one. I decided to give it a formatting, to restore its original size. I backed up all my stuff by copying the files and folders onto my Windows PC (the copying process went just fine, no errors or anything, so I assumed all my stuff was properly backed up), then I erased the hard drive by using this command in OS X terminal on my mac:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1 bs=1m
```

I used this command because I wanted to make sure that my hard drive was completely empty, so I can create a fresh new partition on it. So I created a partition on it (which showed up to be 1TB, so I was happy about that), but when I wanted to copy my stuff back onto it, I realized that only a fraction of my data is present on my PC. I have no idea why it didn't back up everything. I selected all the files on the hard drive when backing them up, and the copying process went fine. Sure, it's my fault that I didn't check whether the data was backed up properly, but I assumed it was.

Anyway, is there any way to recover data from a hard drive that has been zeroed out? I lost a lot of personal stuff... :(

Answer (score 3):

You zeroed the whole disk, it's gone. dd at its finest has rendered your data safe. Despite some conjectures otherwise, that's all it takes anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
No, there is not a good chance to recover from a hard drive that is zeroed out.
There is chance, but it is very low. and if the formation has done random passes etc. the chance gets lower and nearly zero.
https://askubuntu.com/a/21511/364910